# Use acl in backend / shrink my config

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

In my scenario I must switch servers based on an containing url string `&mode=edit` or `&mode=create` between my servers to balance the load. My config is created via script from about 100 different urls/ip. My current way with one frontend and 2 backends is pretty long and the huge amount of health checks are not good for my servers...

How can I put these stuff together in one `listen`instead of `frontend`? I can not figure out how to use ACLs in an listen to determine which server to use.

```
frontend myFrontend

    bind 127.0.0.1:80
    bind 127.0.0.1:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/myFrontend/myFrontend.pem
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    use_backend myBackend-edit if { url_sub &mode=edit } or { url_sub &mode=create }
    default_backend myBackend

backend myBackend

    server srv1 1.1.1.1:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check
    server srv2 2.2.2.2:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup
    server srv3 3.3.3.3:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup

backend myBackend-edit

    server srv1 1.1.1.1:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup
    server srv2 2.2.2.2:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup
    server srv3 3.3.3.3:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the right keyword is `use-server` (notice that this is an dash and not an underscore like `use_backend`. Now my Load is reduced and configs are smaller.  I only searched for something like *use_server*...

So this is my working example:

```
listen myFrontend

    bind 127.0.1.1:80
    bind 127.0.1.1:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/myFrontend/myFrontend.pem
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    use-server srv2 if { url_sub &mode=edit } or { url_sub &mode=create }
    server srv1 1.1.1.1:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check
    server srv2 2.2.2.2:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup
    server srv3 3.3.3.3:10201 cookie srv1 ssl check backup
```

you can also use load-balancing there and stick with cookies if you like.

source: [haproxy manpage](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.5/doc/configuration.txt) | [or use the pretty one :)](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-use-server)